# How to find specific list among other lists

Tags: python, list

I am a beginner in python and have a question.
I am using python 3.6.0
How do I find the name of a list which contains specific items, among other lists?

```
C1 = ['X', 'O', '1', '1']
C2 = ['X', 'O', '2', '1']
C3 = ['X', 'O', '3', '1']
C4 = ['X', 'O', '4', '1']
C5 = ['X', 'O', '5', '1']
C6 = ['X', 'O', '1', '2']
C7 = ['X', 'O', '2', '2']
C8 = ['X', 'O', '3', '2']
C9 = ['X', 'O', '4', '2']
C10 = ['X', 'O', '5', '2']
C11 = ['X', 'O', '1', '3']
C12 = ['X', 'O', '2', '3']
C13 = ['X', 'O', '3', '3']
C14 = ['X', 'O', '4', '3']
C15 = ['X', 'O', '5', '3']
C16 = ['X', 'O', '1', '4']
C17 = ['X', 'O', '2', '4']
C18 = ['X', 'O', '3', '4']
C19 = ['X', 'O', '4', '4']
C20 = ['X', 'O', '5', '4']
C21 = ['X', 'O', '1', '5']
C22 = ['X', 'O', '2', '5']
C23 = ['X', 'O', '3', '5']
C24 = ['X', 'O', '4', '5']
C25 = ['X', 'O', '5', '5']
```

Let's say I wanted to find the name of the list which has 5 in the third position and 2 in the 4 position. How and what do I code to get the name of the list?

Comment: Loop through the lists; check third position; if there is a 5, check fourth position; if there is a 2, you got your list. Return the name of the list. Now just replace my sentence with some code.

Comment: You cannot find the name of the list, because variables don't work like that in python. Instead create a list of lists, i.e. [['X', 'O', '1', '1'], ['X', 'O', '2', '1'], ...] and then do what @DavidG said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Find the name of the list which has 5 in the third position and 2 in the 4 position. How and what do I code to get the name of the list?

You can check the content in each list name to see if that list contains the desired condition.

However, I assume you don't want to type "C1", "C2" all the way to "C25". So here you can use the keyword:  "[eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)".

This way you don't have to concatenate your small lists into a big list.

> Sample Usage:
>
> >>> x = 1
>
> >>> print eval('x+1')
>
> 2

```
for i in range(1, 26):
    ListName = "C"+str(i)
    if eval(ListName)[2] == "5" and eval(ListName)[3] == "2":
        print(ListName, "is the list you are looking for!")
```

Answer (score 1):

Put these lists in a list, and iterate over them using a loop.

```
for listItem in bigList:
    if listItem[2] == '5' and listItem[3] == '2'
         # do something with the listItem
         # this is the list satisfying the condition you wanted
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this ?

```
cList = []
c9 = ['X', 'O', '5', '2']
c10 = ['X', 'O', '5', '2']
# .....
cList.append(c9)
cList.append(c10)
for cItem in cList:
    if '5' == cItem[2] and '2' == cItem[3]:
        print("YES!")
```